# sorting data from array of objects and push data from its value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I'm a beginner in javascript.

I have an some array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    checkInStatus: 'pending',
    overtimeStatus: 'pending',
    checkOutStatus: 'success'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    checkInStatus: 'success',
    overtimeStatus: 'pending',
    checkOutStatus: 'success'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    checkInStatus: 'pending',
    overtimeStatus: 'success',
    checkOutStatus: 'success'
  }
]
```

And want to transform it into something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    checkInStatus: 'pending'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    overtimeStatus: 'pending'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    overtimeStatus: 'pending'
   },
  {
    id: 3,
    checkInStatus: 'pending'
  }
]
```

I want to transform from the first data to the second data, how can this be achieved?

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: I want to transform from the first data to the second data, how is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
const yourData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    checkInStatus: 'pending',
    overtimeStatus: 'pending',
    checkOutStatus: 'success'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    checkInStatus: 'success',
    overtimeStatus: 'pending',
    checkOutStatus: 'success'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    checkInStatus: 'pending',
    overtimeStatus: 'success',
    checkOutStatus: 'success'
  }
]

const pending = [];
for(const entry of yourData){
  for(const property in entry){
    if(entry[property] === 'pending'){
      pending.push({ id: entry.id, [property]: entry[property] });
    }
  }
}
console.log(pending); // Matches your output requirement
```